# wordpress password reset link not work

Tags: php, wordpress, email

on my WordPress website when i reset my account password by entering my email and pressing reset on the lost-password page, i get the confirmation to check my email for confirmation link, 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I49oc.png)
however i never get the email, the email doesn't reach the inbox neither the spam folder, in other words the email does not go.
Why could that be?
Emails from other forms from the website work, contact, registration, product purchase.
I am using woo-commerce on the website.
How can i overcome this?

Comment: Not quite; just because you don't get the email doesn't mean it isn't sent. Can you find the appropriate bit of code that's sending the reminder? Can you add some checking to it to see if the email is actually being sent? It's quite possible that the email is getting blocked by an intermediate server somewhere along the way.

Comment: i think its an issue with woocommerce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to   yourwebsite/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword

then u can change ur password

dont go to  my-account/lost-password/  as woocommerce get you to it

for more info go to https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form